# Xcode 13.1 missing build succeeded or failed notification

Tags: ios, xcode

got an issue with the new Xcode, v13.1. When I make a new build there's no pop-up that build succeeded or failed. If it succeeds, I cant tell immediately. On the previous versions, like 12.5, you would get a nice pop-up telling you the build succeeded or failed.

Is there a way to get this back or? Here are mine Xcode behaviour settings. Any help would be welcome, specially if this CAN be fixed. If not, oh well... :)

[image]

Comment: You probably mean the big square HUD in the middle of the screen? That was abolished years ago. It wasn't in Xcode 12 either. You can still get the user notification at the top right of the screen, however. (That's the system notification referred to in your screenshot.) Still, the best indication is the project window. Look in the toolbar or (even better) the Reports navigator to see what happened. If you preferred the HUD, file an enhancement request with Apple.

Comment: By the way, sometimes the "notify using system notification" option needs you to uncheck it and check it again. When you do that, you get the notification. I have mine set as an Alert so that it stays sitting at the upper right of the screen. I think that's a good substitute for the old center-of-the-screen HUD. Basically system notifications are the new correct way to do this kind of thing and you should just accept that. But, as I say, if you think you have a use case to the contrary, submit it to Apple.

Comment: I second this post, why do people are downvoting? I disagree with @matt, I just tried: Xcode 12.5.1 **is** showing a nice square _build succeeded_ popup at the center of the screen, which disappeared in Xcode 13. Xcode 13 even silence the unit tests success/fail notification! The "notify using system notification" & "Bounce Xcode" only work if Xcode is not focused.

Comment: @Martin I disagree. I get the system notification on build success / fail and on test success / fail, and I get it even when Xcode is frontmost.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with Apple's decision here, but I've already answered that, twice: to protest against the loss of the HUD, file a bug. In any case this is not a programming question so it is not suitable for Stack Overflow. It isn't really even a question. It's just a lament.

Comment: So that is a bug. And yes, we should file it.

Comment: Oh, it seems that xcode 13.2 (at least beta 2) just solved this problem!